# How to fix "update of view in private qgis.db failed"?

Tags: qgis

Would anyone know why I keep getting this error message after installing Valmiera from Durfour?

[image: Private qgis.db error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what circumstances lead to the error message in your installation, I did not get it.

You can savely remove the qgis.db from your user/.qgis2 directory. Valmiera will create a new one, which should not be locked (as long as you have full rights on the folder).

Comment: Hi Andre, thank you for the solution. could you provide a sample pathline to qgis.db - i cannot find it, even with a desktop and pc search functions. much appreciated.

Comment: Heres another error message entitled "Crash dumped": Minidump written to C\Users\XXX\AppData\Local|Temp\qgis-20140318-154727-2520-7444-c3a2817.dmp

Comment: It should be in C:\Users\xxx\.qgis2. Did you use standalone 32bit/64bit or OSGeo4w/OSGeo4w64? You can try one of the others. To my mind, the 32bit version still runs best.

Comment: i always download 32 bit. and the OSGeo4w is always installed with the entire package. thanks for the pathfile, Andre. Hopefully that will help!

Comment: Hi Andre. This solution works beautifully, even with other error messages! Thank you! :D)))